# insert clob datatype in oracle, mule 4?

Tags: oracle, mule, mulesoft

I'm migrating code from Mule 3 to Mule 4 and stuck with the requirement where I need to insert Clob in Oracle database. In Mule 3 I used to change MIME Type of incoming xml to **'binary/octet-stream'** and then again change it to **application/java** and then it used to go in database without any issue.

Now in Mule 4 we do not have 'binary/octet-stream' but we have 'application/octet-stream' which is not working for me. While inserting values I get *'Invalid column type.'* from database.

Can anyone please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any working solution, so wrote a simple Java class and called it from my flow. That is temporary solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

Give value to your field like below:

For json type: `'YourFieldName' :write(payload, "application/json")`

For xml type: `'YourFieldName' :write(payload, "application/xml")`